# NULL pointers in C: If I initialize a pointer ptr1 = NULL, and another pointer ptr2 = ptr1, will ptr2 have value NULL?

Tags: c, pointers, null

If I have the following code:

```
int* ptr1 = NULL;
int* ptr2 = ptr1;
```

Will ptr2 have value NULL?

Comment: what warning you got?

Comment: If, instead of having pointers and structures, you have simple `int` variables, would you still ask the same question? I.e. `int n1 = 0; int n2 = n1;` That is the exact same thing.

Comment: I suggest you take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then edit your question to ask about the *real* problem you have, the warnings.

Comment: There is nothing in the code posted that would generate a warning.

Comment: I later realized that the warning I received was for a different reason. I have modified the question. Also, with that taken out of the equation, my question is now essentially how the NULL pointer works. As per what I've read online, the first pointer would store 0 as its "memory location", and hence the second pointer would take the same value as the first, i.e., 0. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

If the code in the question is executed, `node2` will be `NULL`.

That being said, I would consider the assignment as non-idiomatic; if both pointers should be initialized to `NULL` the following code would be clearer.

```
struct node* node1 = NULL;
struct node* node2 = NULL;
```